# edit column in pdo select

Tags: php, arrays

I have a column that is in seconds and I need to format it in Minutes:seconds, I am thinking that I will need to loop through the fetched array but not quite sure on how to go about that.

```
$query = 'SELECT calldate,recordingfile,uniqueid,clid,did,lastapp,dst,disposition,duration FROM cdr'; 
$sql = $remotedbh->prepare($query);  
$sql->execute(); 
$dblist = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

while($row -)


if($sql->rowCount() > 0){ 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($dblist); 
} 
else {
    echo 0; 
}     

?>
```

Comment: what does this: while($row -) do and what is the name of the seconds column that you are trying to format ?

Comment: Sorry the while was a accidently paste lol, the column is duration.

Comment: I understand how to do the grunt work of changing the seconds into minutes etc, I just need to know how to loop through the column data and keep it all intact, is there a while(til end of array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest changing the value in the query itself.  Here is an example

```
SELECT calldate,
recordingfile,
uniqueid,
clid,
did,
lastapp,
dst,
disposition,
duration,
CONCAT(FLOOR(duration/60),':',LPAD((duration % 60), 2, '0')) AS duration_in_mins_and_secs
FROM cdr
```

Here I am assuming duration is the field you want to modify.  I am simply dividing the duration by 60 to get minute component and then concatenating the remainder to it.

If you need this data regularly (i.e. you are going to perform this query a lot), it would probably be best to actually store this calculated field in the records themselves so you don't need to make a calculation at all when querying the data.  Simply make this calculation upon each record insert.

Comment: +1 Agree, probably best to do it in the query itself rather than post-processing.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/wushuass/public_html/pbx/php/connect/searchtablequery.php on line 26. I just copied and pasted what you put there, how do i need to handle the :

Comment: That is a PHP error.  I didn't provide any PHP code at all.  My guess is you tried to define this query in single quotes, causing `:` to be outside the the string definition because it is surrounded by single quotes as well. It is usually best to work with double quotes around queries so that you don't need to escape single quotes within the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest fetching one row at a time rather than fetching them all into an array:

```
while ($dbrow = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   // process current row
}
```

If you'd rather fetch them all into one array, you can use PHP's `foreach`:

```
$dblist = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

foreach ($dblist as $dbrow) {
  // process current row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will format the duration in `M:S` format:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dur = $row["duration"];
    $min = $sec = 0;
    if (floor($dur / 60) > 0) {
        $min = floor($dur / 60);
        $sec = $dur % 60;
    }
    else {
        $sec = $dur;
    }
    $str = $min . ":" . $sec;
}
```

However, I recommend having your database format the output for you, as Mike Brant specifies in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18859244/2038227).